# Debugging refused ssh connection to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, logging, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have created a new EC2 instance `api1-new` in the same subnet, same VPC and using the same security groups as an old instance `api1-old`. `api1-new` was created from an Ubuntu Linux AMI that already has several users pre-configured, and additionally, I launched it with an Amazon key pair.

1. I cannot connect by `ssh -vvv -p Y my_alias` nor `ssh -vvv -p Y X.X.X.X` from my bastion server, which is in a different subnet from the api1 instances. The first and only error message in the ssh output is:

   > debug1: connect to address X.X.X.X port Y: Connection refused
2. I can connect to `api1-old` from the same bastion server using the same port, logged in as the same user as in 1.
3. I can connect to `api1-new` from my gitlab runner, which is in a third subnet, logged in as the same user as in 1.
4. I can connect from the same bastion server, logged in as the same user, to an instance launched (some time ago, by a colleague) from the same AMI as `api1-new` into the third subnet.
5. I have placed default ACLs (all traffic allowed) on all three subnets involved, but still cannot connect.
6. When I add a ping security group to `api1-new`, I can ping to it from the bastion server, logged in as the same user as in 1.
7. The `$HOME` folder, `$HOME/.ssh` folder and `$HOME/.ssh/authorized-keys` are rigorously the same (permissions and content) on `api1-new`, `api1-old` and on the server mentioned in 4.
8. I cannot connect from the bastion server to `api1-new` using the Amazon key pair I created for launching `api1-new`, whether connecting as ubuntu or as my normal user. The MD5 fingerprint of the private key on the bastion server is identical to what I see in the system log of `api1-new`.

The api1 instances don't have public IP addresses.

I feel I am missing some part of the puzzle in addition to security groups, ACLs and authorized_keys.

I wonder if there is some way to log refused SSH connections on `api1-new` to get the reason why the connection was refused.

**Thanks to wesleywh for the suggestion to look at /etc/ssh/sshd_config!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with your subnets or ssh keys. The fact that you're getting a "connection refused" makes be think your bastion instance is able to see your other ec2 instance just fine. The issue is probably the security group on the "other ec2 instance" itself or how you're supplying your keys.

Open the "other ec2 instance" security group. If your trying to access this instance from port 22 from bastion then add the following to the inbound rules on the "other ec2 instance":

```
Type | Protocol | Port Range | Source      | Description
-----------------------------------------------------------
SSH  |  TCP     |     22     |  sg-1234abc |  Bastion SG
```

Where `sg-1234abc` is the security group id of your bastion ec2 instance. Then try it again.

```
--- FROM LOCAL MACHINE ---
ssh-add -k <path_to_aws_private_key>
ssh-add -k <path_to_bastion_user_private_key>
ssh -A <bastion_user>@<bastion_ip>

--- FROM INSIDE BASTION INSTANCE ---
ssh ec2-user@<other ec2 instance ip>
```

EDIT: Per the comments below also check the following:

Look at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and make sure it's set to accept a custom ssh port if you're planning on using one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting that the problem is not due to the subnet or ssh key. The SG on ```api1-new``` does indeed contain a line like you wrote (but with our custom port Y instead of 22), and I don't think the problem is in the SG, because ```api1-old``` has exactly the same SG and can be connected to from the bastion. That leaves a problem with how the keys are supplied.

Comment: I didn't know about ssh-agent, and it was not running on any of the instances, but I started it up on ```api1-new``` and then ran ```ssh-add -k <bastion_user_private_key>```. ```ssh-add -L``` now shows the identity I supplied, but I still cannot connect. I don't understand your ```ssh -A``` command. Are you suggesting that I should reverse connect **to** the bastion host?

Comment: The ssh -A command allows you to use your keys that you added with ssh-add when you run an ssh command from your bastion instance. If you don't have that then you will not be able to use another key when you connect to your bastion instance. I'm assuming you have different keys to connect to bastion vs your other instances. I didn't have to use -i to supply my key initially either because of the -A command.

Comment: You also mentioned that you are using a custom port instead of port 22. If that is the case make sure your instance is setup correctly to accept from that. Look at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` just to verify you allow things correctly as well. Then make sure you have run the `service sshd restart ` command. This might be difficult to do since you can't access it from bastion. So allow the sg from your ip and try connecting directly to it in the mean time while testing.

Comment: The secret was looking at ```/etc/sshd/sshd_config```: ssh wasn't listening to our custom port. This was the first time I launched an AMI, and the AMI was not created by me, so I hadn't thought of looking outside ```$HOME```.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: Be sure to approve this answer if you feel like this answered it for you :)

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to approve it before, only gave the +1.